# IPhone SDK: Proper way to return a UILabel w/o alloc

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I currently have some code that looks like:

```
-(UIView)someMethod {
  CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
  return label;
}
```

While it *works* it obviously leaks memory and needs to be fixed. I *thought* the fix would be:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel initWithFrame:rect];
```

But the compiler tells me that UILabel doesn't respond to initWithFrame. I guess my question is two-fold:

a) What is the correct way to do this so I'm not leaking memory?

and

b) I'm confused as to why [UILabel alloc] would respond to initWithFrame but not UILabel by itself (my understanding is that UILabel is inherited from UIView that does respond to initWithFrame).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**a)** You can't avoid `+alloc`. But you can use `-autorelease` to relinquish the ownership.

```
-(UIView*)someMethod {
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
  UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect] autorelease];
  return label;
}
```

**b)** `+alloc` is a class method, and `-initWithFrame:` is an instance method. The latter can only be called on <sub><sup>(or, in ObjC terminology, sent to)</sup></sub> an instance of UILabel. However, the symbol "UILabel" is a class, not an instance, so `[UILabel initWithFrame:rect]` won't work. Similarly, a class method like `+alloc` can only be called on a class, so `[label alloc]` won't work.

Comment: but the return type is (UIView*) and function returns (UILabel) !!! is it possible ?

Comment: @Maulik: UILabel is a subclass of UIView.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe more like:

```
-(UILabel)someMethod {

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    return [label autorelease];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

a)

```
 -(UIView *)someMethod {
    return [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)] autorelease];
}
```

b) you're misunderstanding the difference between a class method and an instance method.

a class method is declared and used like so:

```
// declaration: notated with +
+ (NSDocumentController *)sharedDocumentController;
// usage
NSDocumentController * thang = [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];
```

a instance method is declared and used like so:

```
// declaration: notated with -
- (id)init;
// usage:
// + alloc is a class method
//     this requests the class (NSObject) to allocate and return a newly allocated NSObject
// - init is the instance method
//     this sends a message to the NSObject instance (returned by [NSObject alloc])
NSObject * thang = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

in your example, `alloc` returns an allocated instance, which you are then expected to call an appropriate init instance method on.

some classes provide convenience constructors, which often return an autoreleased instance:

```
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithInt:(int)anInt;
```

but it is not terribly common to duplicate code in this manner, unless you're working with advanced topics such as class clusters. of course, it may be a good idea to add this to the interface if you find you regularly need a particular functionality or convenience constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just use your original method and use

```
return [label autorelease];
```

instead.